# How to print GC Details for hosted apps in Heroku -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:gc.log

Tags: java, logging, heroku, garbage-collection, cloud

We have an application hosted on Heroku and logs are getting redirected to Sumologic. I see some options can be passed to JVM where log files will be generated locally.

```
-XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:gc.log
```

Question: Is there a way we can redirect these logs to cloud log analyzers like Splunk, SumoLogic, or Datadog?

Answer (score 0):

Anything printed to STDOUT will be sent to your logging addons like SumoLogic. The options you've shown should take care of that.

The mechanism that addons like SumoLogic use is call [Log Drains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains), and you can tap into that your self to get your log stream over HTTP.